# How can I resolve intermittent Xdebug connection losses in PhpStorm and Docker?

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm running on a Mac in a docker (v4.9.1) container:

- PHP 7.2.34
- Xdebug v2.6.1
- PhpStorm 2023.2.3

I have a running debugging session.
I step through the code.
I go away from PhpStorm and leave the debugging in its current state. I do something else in the meantime.

When I come back and want to go on with my debugging, it seems like the debugging connection is lost.

When I go to my browser, the page is still loading (like it is when I am still in debugging mode).

So I have to go into my docker container and end the specific httpd process so that I can start a new debugging session.

What can I do to prevent this debugging connection from being lost?

Comment: You need to find out with `strace` and `xdebug.log/xdebug.log_level=11` what's going on. But your PHP and Xdebug are so outdated, that this might be fruitless. Xdebug's log only got useful in Xdebug 3.